# No suitable staging package found in do_populate_sysroot_setscene task

Tags: yocto

From yesterday, i am seeing the below error while building Yocto Images, my branch of Yocto is warrior.

```
WARNING: run-postinsts-1.0-r10 do_populate_lic_setscene: Failed to fetch URL file://6c/sstate:run-postinsts::1.0:r10::3:6c1c014b5ff1f03a4bf647fd7419b042aa4c6a148d360d5b9a12d40be8aad4bf_populate_lic.tgz;downloadfilename=6c/sstate:run-postinsts::1.0:r10::3:6c1c014b5ff1f03a4bf647fd7419b042aa4c6a148d360d5b9a12d40be8aad4bf_populate_lic.tgz, attempting MIRRORS if available
ERROR: run-postinsts-1.0-r10 do_populate_lic_setscene: Fetcher failure: Unable to find file file://6c/sstate:run-postinsts::1.0:r10::3:6c1c014b5ff1f03a4bf647fd7419b042aa4c6a148d360d5b9a12d40be8aad4bf_populate_lic.tgz;downloadfilename=6c/sstate:run-postinsts::1.0:r10::3:6c1c014b5ff1f03a4bf647fd7419b042aa4c6a148d360d5b9a12d40be8aad4bf_populate_lic.tgz anywhere. The paths that were searched were:
    /home/mjamal/am335x-test/sstate
    /home/mjamal/am335x-test/sstate
WARNING: dnf-native-4.1.0-r0 do_populate_lic_setscene: Failed to fetch URL file://ca/sstate:dnf-native::4.1.0:r0::3:ca5fbf0c733b0093d2e5091ca86d732109c26c508490c60ff01bdf61f99e4a85_populate_lic.tgz;downloadfilename=ca/sstate:dnf-native::4.1.0:r0::3:ca5fbf0c733b0093d2e5091ca86d732109c26c508490c60ff01bdf61f99e4a85_populate_lic.tgz, attempting MIRRORS if available
ERROR: dnf-native-4.1.0-r0 do_populate_lic_setscene: Fetcher failure: Unable to find file file://ca/sstate:dnf-native::4.1.0:r0::3:ca5fbf0c733b0093d2e5091ca86d732109c26c508490c60ff01bdf61f99e4a85_populate_lic.tgz;downloadfilename=ca/sstate:dnf-native::4.1.0:r0::3:ca5fbf0c733b0093d2e5091ca86d732109c26c508490c60ff01bdf61f99e4a85_populate_lic.tgz anywhere. The paths that were searched were:
    /home/mjamal/am335x-test/sstate
    /home/mjamal/am335x-test/sstate
ERROR: dnf-native-4.1.0-r0 do_populate_lic_setscene: No suitable staging package found
ERROR: dnf-native-4.1.0-r0 do_populate_lic_setscene: 
WARNING: Logfile for failed setscene task is /home/mjamal/am335x-test/build-am335x-evm-test/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/dnf-native/4.1.0-r0/temp/log.do_populate_lic_setscene.16814
ERROR: run-postinsts-1.0-r10 do_populate_lic_setscene: No suitable staging package found
ERROR: run-postinsts-1.0-r10 do_populate_lic_setscene: 
WARNING: Logfile for failed setscene task is /home/mjamal/am335x-test/build-am335x-evm-test/tmp/work/all-poky-linux/run-postinsts/1.0-r10/temp/log.do_populate_lic_setscene.16817
WARNING: Setscene task (virtual:native:/home/mjamal/am335x-test/src/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/dnf/dnf_4.1.0.bb:do_populate_lic_setscene) failed with exit code '1' - real task will be run instead
WARNING: Setscene task (/home/mjamal/am335x-test/src/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/run-postinsts/run-postinsts_1.0.bb:do_populate_lic_setscene) failed with exit code '1' - real task will be run instead
WARNING: dosfstools-native-4.1-r0 do_populate_sysroot_setscene: Failed to fetch URL file://universal/ff/sstate:dosfstools-native:x86_64-linux:4.1:r0:x86_64:3:fff8fc0804ff998a466c0e931884ca93e21f24d165431f5d6f208213a82e1d50_populate_sysroot.tgz;downloadfilename=universal/ff/sstate:dosfstools-native:x86_64-linux:4.1:r0:x86_64:3:fff8fc0804ff998a466c0e931884ca93e21f24d165431f5d6f208213a82e1d50_populate_sysroot.tgz, attempting MIRRORS if available
ERROR: dosfstools-native-4.1-r0 do_populate_sysroot_setscene: Fetcher failure: Unable to find file file://universal/ff/sstate:dosfstools-native:x86_64-linux:4.1:r0:x86_64:3:fff8fc0804ff998a466c0e931884ca93e21f24d165431f5d6f208213a82e1d50_populate_sysroot.tgz;downloadfilename=universal/ff/sstate:dosfstools-native:x86_64-linux:4.1:r0:x86_64:3:fff8fc0804ff998a466c0e931884ca93e21f24d165431f5d6f208213a82e1d50_populate_sysroot.tgz anywhere. The paths that were searched were:
    /home/mjamal/am335x-test/sstate
    /home/mjamal/am335x-test/sstate
ERROR: dosfstools-native-4.1-r0 do_populate_sysroot_setscene: No suitable staging package found
ERROR: dosfstools-native-4.1-r0 do_populate_sysroot_setscene: 
WARNING: Logfile for failed setscene task is /home/mjamal/am335x-test/build-am335x-evm-test/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/dosfstools-native/4.1-r0/temp/log.do_populate_sysroot_setscene.16815
WARNING: Setscene task (virtual:native:/home/mjamal/am335x-test/src/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/dosfstools/dosfstools_4.1.bb:do_populate_sysroot_setscene) failed with exit code '1' - real task will be run instead
WARNING: bzip2-native-1.0.6-r5 do_populate_lic_setscene: Failed to fetch URL file://a1/sstate:bzip2-native::1.0.6:r5::3:a12aff19f9a6b06878c5f23c668abbc6e826b9a415bae5efbde996e4cfff624d_populate_lic.tgz;downloadfilename=a1/sstate:bzip2-native::1.0.6:r5::3:a12aff19f9a6b06878c5f23c668abbc6e826b9a415bae5efbde996e4cfff624d_populate_lic.tgz, attempting MIRRORS if available
ERROR: bzip2-native-1.0.6-r5 do_populate_lic_setscene: Fetcher failure: Unable to find file file://a1/sstate:bzip2-native::1.0.6:r5::3:a12aff19f9a6b06878c5f23c668abbc6e826b9a415bae5efbde996e4cfff624d_populate_lic.tgz;downloadfilename=a1/sstate:bzip2-native::1.0.6:r5::3:a12aff19f9a6b06878c5f23c668abbc6e826b9a415bae5efbde996e4cfff624d_populate_lic.tgz anywhere. The paths that were searched were:
    /home/mjamal/am335x-test/sstate
    /home/mjamal/am335x-test/sstate
ERROR: bzip2-native-1.0.6-r5 do_populate_lic_setscene: No suitable staging package found
ERROR: bzip2-native-1.0.6-r5 do_populate_lic_setscene: 
WARNING: Logfile for failed setscene task is /home/mjamal/am335x-test/build-am335x-evm-test/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/b
```